# speech recognition not working mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

i am trying to implement speech recognition functionality on a Mac xcode project . I am using the NSSpeechRecognizer class . When i run the project using the following code i get a window with message:
A 0 bytes download is required to use speech recognition features in
You may need to quit and open project again after download completes
I press the download button,quit and open the project , but nothing changes , when i run the project i get the same window and the speech recognition is not working. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
NSArray *cmds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sing", @"Jump", @"Roll over", 
nil];
recog = [[NSSpeechRecognizer alloc] init]; // recog is an ivar
[recog setCommands:cmds];
[recog setDelegate:self];
}
- (IBAction)listen:(id)sender
{
if ([sender state] == NSOnState) { // listen
[recog startListening];
} else {
[recog stopListening];
}
}
- (void)speechRecognizer:(NSSpeechRecognizer *)sender didRecognizeCommand:
(id)aCmd
{
if ([(NSString *)aCmd isEqualToString:@"Sing"]) {
NSSound *snd = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
pathForResource:@"HappyBirthday" ofType:@"aif"] byReference:NO];
[snd play];
return;
}
if ([(NSString *)aCmd isEqualToString:@"Jump"]) {
return;
}
if ([(NSString *)aCmd isEqualToString:@"Roll over"]) {
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: i hope this is ok, do you have any idea regarding the problem, please?

Comment: I am having the same problem in my app ! If you have find any solution please post it here :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences > Dictation & Speech, set Dictation to on and select "Use Enhanced Dictation". After dictation data has been downloaded NSSpeechRecognizer should successfully initialise.

Comment: In macOS High Sierra open System Preferences > Keyboard > Dictation and change Dictation to On